# Scraping UPDATED source code from XHR response of a website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

A website url **[www.example.com/abc](http://www.example.com/abc)** does not change when iterating over different pages. After inspecting using DEV TOOLS on CHROME browser XHR tab it is noticed that POST request is posted to url **[www.example.com/abc-data](http://www.example.com/abc-data)** and based on which response source code of url **[www.example.com/abc](http://www.example.com/abc)** changes.

However 90% of the data is being returned and can be scraped from XHR response, but 10% of the data is present in dynamic source code which is updated depending on XHR response.

I've tried all the possible available solutions on internet but not able to crack the solution for this problem.

Env:
Mac OS X Ventura
Python 3.7.3

Note: Using BeautifulSoup

**Short code snippet**

```
url1 = www.example.com/abc
url2 = www.example.com/abc-data
with requests.Session() as s:
r = s.get(url1) # Extract token from this URL
# SOME CODE HERE
r = s.post(url2, data=payload) # Use token from above for this URL and session
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
```

After POST request as above, HTML SOURCE CODE is updated and I am not able to get that using BeautifulSoup.
What I am receiving is just JSON response.

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: It needs some more information about website or used url to answer more specific. What's wrong with using the information from the JSON response?

Comment: JSON response not providing all the data i need. A url link is generated after clicking on search button which is not available in json response. This link can be scraped from html generated which i am not able to fetch

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you're trying to get the dynamic content of a web page using BeautifulSoup. That is not possible to do. BeautifulSoup only scrapes static web content.

If you really want to get the **Dynamic Content**, I recommend using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: *get the dynamic content of a web page using BeautifulSoup. That is not possible to do...* This is not correct `BeautifulSoup` is primarily concerned with parsing HTML / XML it has nothing to do with retrieving the information itself. It is rather a property of the module `requests` which, unlike a browser, does not render content dynamically.